# ScrollView with a UIRefreshControl won't refresh when presented as a modal sheet

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, ios13

iOS 13 modal presentation sheets (UIPresentationController) and UIScrollView's (UITableView/UICollectionView) with UIRefreshControl don't get along well.

Is it possible to drag beyond the top of a TableView to trigger the refresh control instead of dismissing the presented view? Is there any clean solution to this instead of playing around with preset UIGestureRecognizer's?

Setting `isModalInPresentation` to `false` does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Use

`scrollView.refreshControl = refreshControl`

instead of

`scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate there is also some sample code from Apple here https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/224/ "Disabling Pulling Down a Sheet" that might help.

Comment: Same result as what i currently have, instead of continuing to scroll inside the ScrollView it just pulls down the presented view controller.

Comment: ok seems like a weird interaction you are trying to offer, once you have an presented a modal, i don't think interaction with the presenting view is supported, hence "modal"

Comment: I’m trying to refresh a collectionview with a uirefreshcontrol, doesn’t sound like a weird interaction to me

Comment: inside a modally presented view? (just trying to understand ;-))

Comment: Right! Just want to present a view controller using the default iOS 13 sheet and have a collectionview which can be updated using refreshcontrol

Comment: so presumably you want dismissal of the presented view to occur via a "cancel/hide/done" button and not the gesture, because you want the gesture (pull down) to activate a pull to refresh?

Comment: Exactly, and/or by dragging down the navigationbar in the presented view if possible.

Answer (score 0):

try to presenting `viewController` using below code and check it.

```
let vc = UIViewController()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen 
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```